# How to access .bin scripts of sub-dependencies using in node_modules/

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-scripts

I am trying to build something like `react-scripts`/`kcd-scripts`

[image: 64929817_376390323276635_2450497095426113536_n]

Assuming as per the image above `library` is where I want to consume `my-scripts` (Package A) which has all the dependencies installed like `eslint`, `prettier` etc.

All the `.bin/` scripts for ESLint, Prettier are available in my `node_modules/` for `my-scripts` (Package A)

And when I consume `my-scripts` (Package A) in `library` all the peer-dependencies from `Package A` are available in `library` in my `node_modules/` but the `.bin/` scripts are not.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Anyone trying to understand more on how react-scripts work check this cool wiki out https://github.com/danielbischoff/shared-webpack-config/wiki

Answer (score 0):

Closing this issue

Resources that helped me https://github.com/danielbischoff/shared-webpack-config/wiki
& obviously spending more time understanding kcd-scripts/react-scripts

Solution:

I need to export prettier/eslint using stuff like eslint CliEngine in `Package A` to be consumed in library.

---